# What are the difference between $L^2(S^2) $ and $L^2(T^2)$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

$S^2$ is 2-dim sphere , $T^2$ is 2-dim torus. $L^2$ is Lebesgue spaces.   What is the *difference* of $L^2(S^2)$ and $L^2(T^2)$ ?

In fact, I don't know how to define the *difference* ,because isomorphism of Hilbert space can't distinguish them. But I  feel there should be some difference.

This is a loose question, I am sorry for this , but I really don't know how to ask it exactly.

Comment: Well, one space contains (equivalence classes of) functions on $S^2$ and the other contains functions on $T^2$... I don't really understand what you're asking. It is true that the spaces are isometric which is sometimes a useful thing to know but it doesn't mean that they are the same... you could have asked "What is the difference between $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the vector space of real-valued polynomials of degree $\leq 2$?" and the answer would have been the same: "They are different (the underlying sets are different, the addition is defined differently, etc), but are linearly isomorphic."

Comment: @levap   So, what is the difference of functions on $S^2$ and $T^2$ ? how to describe the difference , and how the difference will be drown when put them into $L^2$ ?   In fact, I am not  clear to my question. Sorry about this vague question.

Comment: Somehow, you should not even compare them! It is like asking what is the difference between $L^2$ of the unit segment vs whole R. They are different function spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't apply to Hilbert spaces, but you might be interested in the fact that if you shift your attention to Banach **algebras** you have the [Gelfand Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation#Gelfand_representation_of_a_commutative_Banach_algebra), which I think of as a way to go from a function/operator space back to the underlying topological space. I think this addresses the underlying spirit of your 'loose' question.

If that scratches your itch, you could look into [Noncommutative Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_geometry), which takes the ideas further.

Answer (score 3):

Naturally, the first Hilbert space is a representation of $SO(3)$, and splits explicitely as an orthonormal Hilbert sum of finite dimensional irreducible representation of $SO(3)$ (theory of spherical harmonics), whereas the second is a representation of the abelian group $R/Z^2$ and splits as the direct sum of (one dimensional) representation of this group (Fourier series).

But of course as separable Hilbert spaces they are isomorphic.